# Webserver failover with VMs on Two esxi 5.1

Tags: vmware-esxi, high-availability

I have two server on datacenter with two websites abc.com, cde.com, and my model :

### ESXi 1

- NIC1 113.11.11.11 from ISP
- NIC2 192.168.1.1 cross connect NIC2 ESXi2

  - VM CentOS6 iptables1
  - HA proxy1 failover with HA proxy2 on ESXi2
  - VM CentOS6 apache1 rsync with apache2 on ESXi2
  - VM CentOS6 mysql1 replicate with mysql2 on ESXi2

### ESXi 2

- NIC1 113.11.11.12 from ISP
- NIC2 192.168.1.2 cross connect NIC2 ESXi1

  - VM CentOS6 iptables2
  - HA proxy2 failover
  - VM CentOS6 apache2
  - VM CentOS6 mysql2

When ESXi1 down the client can't connect to websites because abc.com, cde.com point to IP 113.11.11.11 of ESXi1.

When one of them down the client still connect websites. How to do that?

Pls advise me!
Many thanks

Comment: Do you not have an independent switch or router for handling all your traffic? if not you should consider doing so as it looks like you have a design-flaw here.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, you would do:

- Create a HA Firewall on your ESX (e.g. pfsense)
- Let that FW have a VIP with an external IP
- Port-Forward that IP to the HA Proxy internal VIP

Also, as @Chopper3 suggests, you should add a Switch, proper VLAN's and all that stuff.

Comment: It sounds like they already have a HA configuration (I see two firewalls and two load balancers) -- they're just grossly misconfigured.

Comment: Ah, missed the IPTables box. But yes, should give a general idea on what to do nonetheless

Answer (score 1):

High Availability -- You're Doing It.... not exactly correctly.

Your existing setup has two IP addresses - presumably 113.11.11.11 points to the load balancer on `ESXi 1` and 113.11.11.12 points to the one on `ESXi 2`.
For the configuration you've got documented above you need at least 3 IP addresses:

113.11.11.11 --> ESXi 1
113.11.11.12 --> ESXi 2
113.11.11.13 --> Shared (HA) address that switches back and forth when one server goes down.

Your client requests should be pointed at the *shared* address.
You could configure such a setup using [CARP in pfsense](https://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/Configuring_pfSense_Hardware_Redundancy_(CARP)) or the equivalent on whatever OS you're using.

---

Alternatively you can cross-connect your VMWare environment and take advantage of [VMWare's built-in High Availability capabilities](http://www.vmware.com/files/pdf/VMware-High-Availability-DS-EN.pdf) to migrate the running virtual machine from `ESXi 1` to `ESXi 2` in the event of hardware failure or scheduled maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to get a load balancer. You could set the load balancer with the IP address of 113.11.11.11 and then you would configure the load balancer to send the traffic for  both of your websites to either 192.168.1.1, 192.168.1.2, or both. When one server fails, the load balancer sends all traffic to the other server.